# Append to ArrayList serialized in external file

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of `Strings` stored in an external file. The `ArrayList` is written to the file using serialization, i.e. `ObjectOutputream`. If I want to append the contents of another `ArrayList` of `Strings`, do I need to deserialize the file's `ArrayList` to a new object, append to that, and then reserialize, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Yep, you got it right.  You're persisting the data within the ArrayList to the file.  The only way you can append more data to it is to follow the approach you have already deduced.

Answer (score 0):

That is the only way I know of.  I don't know of a way Java provides to manipulate the file directly and trying to edit it outside of Java (like opening it in Notepad) seems like a lot more trouble than it is worth.

If anyone else knows of some other way, I would like to know also.

Comment: I'm holding out hope for a better answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is an old article that is still relevant today consisting of a set of classes that allow you to perform the saving of Serializable classes to file and vise versa.  I use it myself regularly and it works like a dream.  Check out: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076333/java-web-development/use-a-randomaccessfile-to-build-a-low-level-database.html  This will likely do the trick for you.